# 300ms delay in phonegap

Tags: javascript

The problem I am encountering is I that when I push a button, it takes approximately 300ms to push another button. How can I implement fastclick.js in the script code written below, or what kind of adjustments do I have to make?

[fastclick.js library here](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

```
   $(function(){

            $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
                var row = $(this).attr('data-row');

                 $('.active').removeClass('active');
                 $('#table' + row).addClass('active');
            });             
         });
```

Kind regards,
Dler H.

Comment: Surely the library tells you how to use it? Right?
Once fastclick is included, it should "hijack" all links and make them click faster.

Comment: Thats what I thought, so I just need to include this?
<script type='application/javascript' src='/path/to/fastclick.js'></script>

Comment: @Juhana, sorry mistake was corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**From the doc**](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick#usage)

Include fastclick.js in your JavaScript bundle or add it to your HTML page like this:

```
<script type='application/javascript' src='/path/to/fastclick.js'></script>
```

The script must be loaded prior to instantiating FastClick on any element of the page.

To instantiate FastClick on the body, which is the recommended method of use:

```
if ('addEventListener' in document) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
    }, false);
}
```

Or, if you're using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

Comment: What is document.body? And where should I implement the code : $(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
});

Answer (score 0):

Add the fastclick.js to your index.html. Then add an event listener for 'deviceready'. Inside that add `FastClick.attach(document.body);`. The fastclick library should take care of the rest.